# Css rotate leaves a line in ie9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, transform

I want a link to display as a speech bubble, and the tips of the bubbles are images rotated and positioned to fit. In IE9, there are lines left on the wrong side of the tips (see image), that appear when I rotate them. Can I get rid of those lines somehow?

```
<a class="Bubble Red S  " href="">
<span class="fs20 tac db">Jag söker bostad</span>
```

```
.Bubble {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    .border-radius(1.6rem);
    text-decoration: none !important;
    &:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: -27px;
        left: 50%;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 34px;
        height: 28px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-image: url( "../media/bubble-tip.png" );
    }
     &.S {
        margin: 0 0 2.7rem 0;
        &:after {
            width: 34px;
            height: 25px;
            .transform( ~"rotate(180deg)" );
            bottom: -27px;
            top: auto;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot from ie9]

Comment: I can't recreate your bubble by just copying your code, but I'm suspecting it has to do with text decoration, even though you have written it should be `none`. I've seen something similar before, that's why. Try `.Bubble a {text-decoration: none}`?